# ShinobiCharts x axis labels folding when zoom out

Tags: objective-c, shinobi

Im using ShinobiCharts line type kind ,my x values are date strings and y are the values - longs.

The chars points are displayed correctly but the x values lables are shown along the whole chart points,
and shown on top of each other [image: x labels overlay]

This is chart initialisation I'm using:

```
 mainChart = [[ShinobiChart alloc] initWithFrame:frame   withPrimaryXAxisType:SChartAxisTypeCategory withPrimaryYAxisType:SChartAxisTypeNumber];
```

And this is how i create my dataPoint:

```
SChartDataPoint* dataPoint = [SChartDataPoint new];    
dataPoint.xValue =key;
dataPoint.yValue = value;
```

Any ideas what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your x-axis a SChartDateTimeAxis, not an SChartCategoryAxis. Your xValue needs to be an NSDate, not an NSString. Use the NSDateFormatter to get the dateFromString:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yy";

dataPoint.xValue = [dateFormatter dateFromString:key];
...
```